# TableView is not counting exactly

Tags: xcode6

I pass data(value) from a ViewController to a TableView (see below), but the tableview fill always only the first row. It don´t count. How can I fix it?

The tableview should show every passing data in a new row.

```
 @IBAction func a(sender: UIButton) {
           txtBalkenbewehrung = ausgabe.text        
        performSegueWithIdentifier("transferfile", sender: sender)        
    }                                                                                  
   import UIKit
   var txtBalkenbewehrung: String?

class EBTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



    var rowData = [txtBalkenbewehrung]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.editing = true
        self.tableView.reloadData()


        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return rowData.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("textcell",
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        // let data = rowData[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = rowData[indexPath.row]


        return cell

    }
```

`

Comment: Where do you add new items to the `rowData` array?

Comment: On the ViewController is a Pickerview with deposit values. User multibly this with a textfield input. The result will show in the label ausgabe.text. (see above)This result i will pass with a Add-Button to tableview......Maybe you have a better Idea for passing the data(string) to the tableview?

Comment: If you're only passing one item to a **new** controller, what else do you expect it to display?

Comment: I now what you mean, but i have only one output label. This label change the value when user make a intake. You have an better idea how i can pass the changing results to the tableview? How can I fix the problem? I`m new at swift and I can´t retrace all at this time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please make sure that you correctly format your code!

The behavior seems coherent, as the data is a an array with a single element, txtBalkenbewehrung

You need to fill the array with more element if you want to display more than one

Comment: The element txtBalkenbewehrung is a String and will changed on the ViewController(User Input). I only find this way for passing this data. My target is to save all changing label outputs in a list where i can estimate a total amount and print it /send via Email. Any better idea for it? Thanks